# Use parameter with DB::raw in Laravel 9

Tags: sql, laravel, join, query-builder, raw

I have this SQL query which returns all employees based on selected date :

```
SELECT employees.id as employee_id ,employees_salaries.*,CONCAT(first_name,' ',second_name,' ',third_name) as fullname FROM employees
JOIN employees_salaries
ON employees.id = employees_salaries.employee_id
inner join (
    select employee_id, max(effective_from) as MaxDate
    from employees_salaries
    where effective_from <= '2022-06-31'
    group by employee_id
) innerTable 
on employees_salaries.employee_id = innerTable.employee_id 
and employees_salaries.effective_from = innerTable.MaxDate;
```

and the same query in laravel using query builder like this:

```
$employees = DB::table('employees')
        ->join('employees_salaries', 'employees_salaries.employee_id', 'employees.id')
        ->join(DB::raw('(select employee_id, max(effective_from) as MaxDate from employees_salaries  where effective_from <= \'2022-06-31\' group by employee_id) innerTable'), function ($join) use ($searchDate) {
            $join->on('employees_salaries.employee_id', '=', 'innerTable.employee_id')
                ->on('employees_salaries.effective_from', '=', 'innerTable.MaxDate');
        })
        ->select(DB::raw("employees.id as employee_id,employees_salaries.*,CONCAT(first_name,' ',second_name,' ',third_name) as fullname"))
        ->get();
```

now, the problem is the date in the `where` clause (`where effective_from <= \'2022-06-31\'`),
it should accept a parameter `$searchDate` instead of fixed string. But `DB::raw` seems to not accept any parameters.
I've tried with `selectRaw` but it's not working either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For accepting a parameter, You will have to use double quotes. See the below example.

```
$date = '2022-01-01';
$employees = DB::table('employees')
->join('employees_salaries', 'employees_salaries.employee_id', 'employees.id')
->join(DB::raw("(select employee_id, max(effective_from) as MaxDate from employees_salaries  where effective_from <= {$date} group by employee_id) innerTable"), function ($join) {
    $join->on('employees_salaries.employee_id', '=', 'innerTable.employee_id')
        ->on('employees_salaries.effective_from', '=', 'innerTable.MaxDate');
})
->select(DB::raw("employees.id as employee_id,employees_salaries.*,CONCAT(first_name,' ',second_name,' ',third_name) as fullname"))
->get();
```

Comment: does this prevent sql injections as well ?

Comment: Yes it does, But I would suggest not to use raw queries. You can use Laravel's relationships for better.

Comment: I've read that Laravel Eloquent is slower than query builder. Therefore, I am trying to use query builder as much as possible

Comment: Yeah right, but eloquent can be faster too by using in correct way.  But still DB queries are much faster. Did the above solution work for you?